# How to save username which submits the form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm new to django. I'm trying to create a sports betting game as my first django app. 
I have form, using which I'm able to save home goals and away goals for particular game to database, but I can't find a way to insert a username there. Hope you can help!

Here is my view:

```
@login_required
def group_games(request, groupname):
games = Match.objects.filter(groupname=groupname)
template = loader.get_template('C:\djangoenvs\\typer\\typer\\templates\group_games.html')

username = User.get_username()

for game in games:
    game_id = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=game)

form = BetForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    print ('valid form')
    form.save()
else:
    print ('invalid form')
    print (BetForm.errors)

context = {
    'games': games,
    'groupname': groupname,
    'form': form,
}
```

User.get_username() raises the following error:

```
get_username() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I tried to change it to User.get_username(self) but then:

```
name 'self' is not defined
```

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: Instead of `username = User.get_username()` try doing: `username = request.user.get_username()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.get_username()
```

`User` represents the complete table, not the record. This is why you get an error.

So remove:
`username = User.get_username()`

A user might be able to change their username in your application, you can save a foreign key to the user instead. When you save the form do this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    print ('valid form')
    bet = form.save(commit=False) # the bet isn't saved just yet
    bet.user = request.user # you add the user here
    print bet.user.username
    bet.save() # finally save the bet in the database
```

In your Bet model, you need to add a field to record the user. For example:

```
class Bet(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name="bets", blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Comment: Great @Patr01. Well, you can accept the answer then :)

Comment: @FrançoisConstant how would you go about this, if you are not using Django forms, and submitting the form through ajax, that means you are saving the form manually using `create()` rather than `bet.save()`. In this case how would one get the `username` of the form submitted to do something like this `User.objects.create(username=username)`

Comment: @jam1 could you create a separate question with your code and more details? Short answer: going through AJAX, doesn't change anything, you can still use a `BetForm`.

Comment: @FrançoisConstant Hey I got the problem solved, thanks for your reply